# Particles velocities directly after an inelastic impact with a smooth frictionless surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, velocity, collision

Let us consider the following situation where a dumbbell falls onto a smooth and frictionless surface.

[image]

The dumbbell is formed of 2 particles, each of mass $m$, linked by a massless rod of length $l$. Before impacting with the surface, $\theta=45^{\circ}$ and $\dot\theta=0\,rad.s^{-1}$. Since the surface is smooth, the collision is considered inelastic and there is no rebound.

Now, the only impulse applied to particle 1 upon impact should be vertical since the surface is frictionless. Also, because the collision is inelastic, particle 1 should slide away horizontally from its initial position. Since there is no horizontal impulse, the dumbbell center of mass horizontal linear momentum is equal to zero.

I tried to imagine what would happen directly after the collision (drawn in light gray) and since there is no horizontal impulse, particles 1 and 2 would move horizontally away from their initial positions with the same speed. The center of mass will obviously continue to fall down in a strictly vertically. So, if we take particle 1 as a reference point $P$, particle 2 velocity directly after the impact would be

\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{v}_2 = l\dot\theta\vec{e_\theta} = l\dot\theta \left( -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\vec{i} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\vec{j} \right)
\end{equation}

where $\vec{e_\theta}$ is perpendicular to the radial unit vector; $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$ are unit vectors of the $(x,y)$ frame.

Now, since the two particles are moving horizontally away from their respective initial positions and the center of mass is not, I assume that their horizontal velocities must be equal and opposite. But since the particle 1 already has a velocity after impact, I am not sure if the equation above can hold. Also, since it is an inelastic contact, there should be some velocity loss. All of these factors are confusing to me.

*How am I supposed to be calculating the velocities of these two particles?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to obtain these velocities with calculus. I am sure that one can always try to deduce the particles velocities by mere logic; in fact, more than once, I "thought" about the answer that I finally found. But I was not comfortable without a calculus development.

**Finding the velocity of particle 1**

We can first calculate the velocity of the system center of mass by taking particle 1 as a reference.

\begin{equation}
 \vec{v}_c = \vec{v}_1 + \dot\theta\vec{k} \times \frac{l}{2}\vec{e}_r
\end{equation}

where $\vec{v}_c$ is the system center of mass velocity; $\vec{v}_1$ is the total velocity of particle 1; $\dot\theta\vec{k}$ is the angular velocity around an axis perpendicular to the $(x,y)$ plane; $\times$ is the cross product operator ;and $\vec{e}_r$ is the radial vector along the massless rod.

We know that particle 1 cannot have a vertical velocity because of the assumption of an inelastic collision. So the equation above becomes:

\begin{equation}
 \vec{v}_c = \vec{v}_{1x} + \dot\theta\vec{k} \times \frac{l}{2}\vec{e}_r
\end{equation}

where $\vec{v}_{1x}$ is the horizontal velocity of particle 1. By developing the above equation, we end up with:

\begin{equation}
 \vec{v}_c = \vec{v}_{1x} + \frac{l\dot\theta\sqrt{2}}{4} \left( -\vec{i} + \vec{j} \right)
\end{equation}

Now, if the system center of mass does not move horizontally, that means that the *horizontal component of its velocity has to be zero*. Consequently, in the above equation:

\begin{equation}
 \vec{v}_{1x} - \frac{l\dot\theta\sqrt{2}}{4}\vec{i} = 0 
\end{equation}

and since the vertical velocity of particle 1 is simply zero, then:

\begin{equation}
 \vec{v}_{1} = \frac{l\dot\theta\sqrt{2}}{4}\vec{i}
\end{equation}

**Finding the velocity of particle 2**

The velocity of particle 2 can now be simply calculated as:

\begin{equation}
 \vec{v}_2 = \vec{v}_1 + \dot\theta\vec{k} \times l\vec{e}_r
\end{equation}

and by developing the above equation :

\begin{equation}
 \vec{v}_2 = \frac{l\dot\theta\sqrt{2}}{2} \left( -\frac{1}{2}\vec{i} + \vec{j} \right)
\end{equation}